# Which version of The Intelligent Investor should I read?

Tags: investing, value-investing, books

There seems to be two main editions of The Intelligent Investor, a 300 page original version and 600 page version with Zweig commentary. Is the 600 page version worth the additional time? Does it have a lot more updated modern content?

Comment: Somebody (maybe you?) just asked a very similar question on [goodreads.com](https://www.goodreads.com/questions/2163337-which-version-would-be-better-bogle-s)